# Target single instance of a class

Tags: jquery

I'm using css to hide content that I want to reveal when a person clicks a link. There are multiple instances on the page.

I've set up an example but currently clicking any of the links reveals all of the content.

http://jsfiddle.net/paulyabsley/rHD43/

Thanks

Comment: I'm speechless. A new user, first question, demo fiddle, short concise description. the only thing missing is having the actual fiddle demo code in the question (which I suggest). If only more new users would get it together like this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [`.siblings()`](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/) to find an element with the class `details` that is a sibling of the link's parent element.

```
$('.item h3 a').click(function () {
    $(this).parent().siblings(".details").toggleClass("display");
});​
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/rHD43/28/)

Answer (score 2):

Try this instead:

```
$('.item h3 a').click(function () {
    $(this).parent().next().toggleClass("display");
});​
```

Demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/WxPE4/).

What your current selector is doing is selecting *all* elements that match. What the above snippet does is select the element relative to the one that was clicked, using `$(this)` which is, in this case, the `<a>` that was clicked.

Because the `<a>` is inside the `<h3>`, and the `<div>` is a sibling of the `<h3>` and *not* the `<a>`, you need to use [`$.parent()`](http://api.jquery.com/parent/) to select the `<h3>`, then use [`$.next()`](http://api.jquery.com/next/) to get the next element after the `<h3>`, which is the `<div>` you want to toggle.

---

The better way of doing this would be to bind your click handler to the `<h3>` instead. This simplifies the selector chaining, as well as removing any issues you may have with the `<a>` tag. This would work better, IMO:

```
$('.item h3').click(function () {
    $(this).next().toggleClass("display");
});​
```

Comment: Seeing the way the `a` tag functions, putting the `click` handler on the `h3` instead would make sense and make your original answer (minus `$.parent()`) the best approach IMO.

Comment: @Jared I thought that when I was editing the OP's fiddle, and was about to edit that into my question when my PC had a hissy fit. I've edited it in now, after a reboot.

Comment: I've already voted on the answer, so I can't do so again. But the most elegant solution is that one, although the other is certainly reasonable.

Answer (score 2):

You could go up to the root element and search for the details.

```
$(this).parent().parent().find('.details').toggleClass("display");
```

Answer (score 0):

A slightly more elaborate solution, but it provides functionality to close other  descriptions when you open a new one which I see is lacking from the current answers.

```
$('.item h3 a').click(function () {
    // always try cache your selectors if you plan on using them repeatedly.
    var $details = $(this).parent().next("div.details");

    if ($details.hasClass('display')){
        // if the item we clicked on is already displayed - we want to hide it.
        $details.toggleClass("display");
    }else{
      // now we want to close all other open descriptions      
      $("div.details").removeClass("display");
      // and only display the one we clicked on.
      $details.toggleClass("display",true);    
    }
});​
```

#### [Working example](http://jsfiddle.net/rHD43/53/)

#### [Animated Example](http://jsfiddle.net/rHD43/56/)

Comment: The first `if` isn't necessary and redundant with what happens at the end of the `else` block. You could do the same thing with `$.has()` or `$.filter()` on the group and `addClass()` on the target element for display.

Comment: @jar - Yes - the other answers show it can be done with less but I added the closing of the other elements as well. Or maybe I didn't understand you.  I can't always end with `addClass()`...

Comment: Yes, and I agree it's a value-added approach. I am saying, though, the actual code can be improved. See: http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/rHD43/71/ And note, change `toggleClass()` to `addClass()` if you want it to only open the `details` element.

Comment: And deploying the "improvement" @JamWaffles and I were discussing: http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/rHD43/72/